# Magento 1.9.3 Not able to Add or Edit Product

Tags: magento1.9.3

I am facing an issue after re-indexing not able to add or edit product and old products are not showing.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') ) ) AND
>   (p.entity_id = '2112') LIMIT 1' at line 3, query was: SELECT DISTINCT
>   p.entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `p` INNER JOIN
>   `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `cpf` ON cpf.entity_id = p.entity_id LEFT
>   JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `ccp` ON ccp.product_id =
>   p.entity_id WHERE ( ( (`cpf`.`attribute_set_id`='4' AND ) ) ) AND
>   (p.entity_id = '2112') LIMIT 1

*AND is 2 times, but it comes from magento core before when i didn't do re-indexing i can do edit and update there is no SQL error but after re-indexing its appears*.

*I Checked all the necessary things like (Status,Visibility,Qty ,Stock Availability,Product Categories,Indexes and Caches), but i am not able to add or even edit old products, or not able to view on fronted any product on detail page..*

> app\code\core\Mage\Rule\Model\Resource\Abstract.php

```
public function getProductFlatSelect($storeId, $condition)
{
    $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select();
    $select->from(
            array('p' => $this->getTable('catalog/product')),
            array(new Zend_Db_Expr('DISTINCT p.entity_id'))
        )
        ->joinInner(
            array('cpf' => $this->getTable('catalog/product_flat') . '_' . $storeId),
            'cpf.entity_id = p.entity_id',
            array()
        )->joinLeft(
            array('ccp' => $this->getTable('catalog/category_product')),
            'ccp.product_id = p.entity_id',
            array()
        );

    $where = $condition->prepareConditionSql();
    if (!empty($where)) {
        $select->where($where);
    }

    return $select;
}
```

Comment: Please try with disabled flat option in configuration.

Comment: Hi Anas, Thanks, My half issue resolve by your suggestion now I can Edit or update product.. but I can't see Product custom option on frontend...

Comment: Please check with admin panel it's exist or not.

Comment: All Product are exist, even i get the name of the product on detail page but not able to see Product Options...

Answer (score 1):

The query has the syntax error because some of the catalog rule conditions are incomplete: https://prnt.sc/xnf5zo
When the flat catalog is enabled the query checks also the catalog rules.
You should check all your rules and edit the conditions to solve the issue.